# oracle to postgresql syntax convert

Tags: postgresql, trigger, migration

oracle :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ORA_ADMIN.T_INCOMING_FILE 
BEFORE INSERT ON ORA_ADMIN.INCOMING_FILE FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
 err_num NUMBER;
 err_msg VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
SELECT incoming_file_seq.NEXTVAL into :NEW.ID from dual ;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
  -- throw application error
    err_num := SQLCODE;
    err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 100);
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( 100, 'Insert into incoming_file failed ' ||err_num || err_msg );
END;
/
```

postgresql : what is the equivalent syntax in postgresql?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: I fail to see the purpose of the trigger. It only increments the sequence but does nothing else. I can't imagine any situation where that would actually throw an exception (except when you drop the sequence after you created the trigger). If the trigger is supposed to automatically assign an ID to  a column in the table, then it's not needed at all in Postgres. Just define that column as `serial` or `generated by default as identity` if you are using Postgres 10

Comment: it seems that all this does is enforce default value in the `ID` column and rewrite the error message - how important is that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name perhaps `GENERATED ALWAYS` is a closer match to the behaviour of that trigger than `GENERATED BY DEFAULT`

Comment: @Jasen: The trigger does not "enforce a default value" because it does not modify the inserted rows in any way. And the generated value of the sequence is never checked (or even included in the error message). The code makes no sense

Comment: looks like it modifies `NEW.ID` to me in a before trigger that wil alter the values inserted.

Comment: @Jasen when the trigger goes to exception section?

Comment: when that happens, postgres won't insert anything.  I don't know oracles behavior. it seem likely that exception only hapens if the sequence is exhausted, or if user doesn't have permission for the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are in pl/sql. So its not a big deal to convert the schema. But still, there are many restrictions to convert these kinds of the trigger. I suggest,

http://www.sqlines.com/online

https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/SchemaConversionTool/  (but this will work on top of OLTP, it'll not convert the queries)